# Route with /:userId interrupt other path

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a problem with Route.

I have this code:

```
<Switch>
 <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
 <Route path="/:userId" component={UserProfile} />
 <Route path="/direct/inbox" component={Messenger} />
```

And in the component(UserProfile) i'm using useParams to catch the userId, but my problem is when i tried to go to /direct/inbox its rendering UserProfile's component(and of course giving me error).

So my question is, how can i render other path while using :userId???

***Btw Register's path does not have any problem with that, its working fine.

Comment: I think you have to put the `:userId` route at the bottom after the `/direct/inbox` route

Comment: Thats working as well.. didnt know that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I solve it...
I added 'exact' in the userId path.
If someone have other solution i wont mind trying it.

```
<Switch>
<Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
<Route exact path="/:userId" component={UserProfile} />
<Route path="/direct/inbox" component={Messenger} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `exact` will not solve the issue because if the path is `/direct/inbox` then it will match `exact path="/:userId"`. So what we can do is make             `<Route path="/:userId" component={UserProfile} />` the last route. So when path is being matched for `/direct/inbox` it will match with the expected route and corresponding component will be rendered.